# Mostrar determinada posição de um array javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Quero mostrar a posição que o usuário digitar na função, já consegui gerar o `array` com a sequência mas não consigo mostrar apenas uma posição específica, já tentei usar `fibonacci[n]` mas ele retorna `undefined`.

```
function sequenciaDeFibonacci(n) {
    var fibonacci = []
    fibonacci.push(0)
    fibonacci.push(1)
    for(let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 2] + fibonacci[i - 1];
    }
    console.log(fibonacci)
}

sequenciaDeFibonacci(10)
```

Nesse caso queria que ele retornasse a décima posição do `array` da sequência de fibonacci

Comment: Sim, tem que usar `fibonacci[n]`, mas ou teu for vai até `i <= n` ou exibe `fibonacci[n - 1]`.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual a forma mais curta e a mais performática de escrever fibonnaci em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9953/qual-a-forma-mais-curta-e-a-mais-perform%c3%a1tica-de-escrever-fibonnaci-em-javascrip)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103913/137387

Comment: Sua função não retorna nada (só imprime no console), mas deveria. Use algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/2fmkj1zw/

Answer (score -3):

Você esta lidando com array em Js, então para resolver essa situação tens que saber duas coisas.

**1 -** os arrays em Js começam com index 0(ou seja o index da primeira posição é zero, da segunda posição é um e assim sucessivamente.).

**2 -** quando você deseja mostrar um elemento e você sabe o index dele você deve fazer: `console.log(elemento[index])`

nesse caso eu fiz um ajuste rápido no seu código e testei no DevTools do chrome e aparentemente funcionou, segue abaixo o código:

```
function sequenciaDeFibonacci(n) {
  var fibonacci = []
  fibonacci.push(0)
  fibonacci.push(1)
  for(let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 2] + fibonacci[i - 1];
  }
  console.log(fibonacci[9])
}

sequenciaDeFibonacci(10)
```

no seu caso em vez de `console.log(fibonacci)` o correto seria `console.log(fibonacci[9])`, vale ressaltar que neste primeiro console você estaria receberia como resposta o array completo com todos os elementos, no segundo console você recebe apenas a décima posição do array `fibonacci(décima posição = index 9)`

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9953/qual-a-forma-mais-curta-e-a-mais-perform%c3%a1tica-de-escrever-fibonnaci-em-javascrip) e a partir delas tente melhorar a sua.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).